# updating mesh geometry in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js

I have two meshes: mesh1 and mesh2. both have the same number of vertices and have extrusion.

```
mesh1 = 5000 vertices.
mesh2 = 5000 vertices.
```

I assign the vertices of mesh2 to mesh1. then I do:

```
mesh2.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
mesh2.geometry.vertices = mesh1.geometry.vertices;
```

thus the vertices of mesh2 are updated. but this happens too fast. I can not see an animation while it makes mesh2's vertices to mesh1's vertices.

I want to see the transformation when malla2 starts to become the malla1, I mean to see an animation of vertices when they are changing.

I used "Tween.js" for animations such as position and color. I'm not sure if this can help to view animations when vertices begin to change.

I do:

```
new TWEEN.Tween( mesh2.geometry.vertices ).to( mesh1.geometry.vertices, 1000 ).start();
```

but not works. sorry for my level of english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've seen, this doesn't work -- in part because for each call to update the mesh vertices, you must also call `geometry2.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` for every one of these frames.

--

more specifically I think you will want to add `.onUpdate(function() { geometry2.verticesNeedUpdate = true; })` to your tween.

Comment: thank you! more or less is the solution of my problem.